# Caesar would be pleased

Tags: cipher, code

> U PROP BY THERE, USE PARS PAR THERE PROP
>      BY THERE IYBSM PAR YUCR THER, USE YH HS.
>      THINE BP AUQQRS PAUP PAR HGBMBSUN PROP
>      BY GRUTARE UP YHCR YPUMR?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Answer still in progress

I have decoded the cryptogram as it stands (not manually, but with a website) and it results in this:

> `A TEXT IS CODED, AND THEN THE CODED TEXT IS CODED USING THE SAME CODE, AND SO ON. COULD IT HAPPEN THAT THE ORIGINAL TEXT IS REACHED AT SOME STAGE?`

I haven't found the answer to this yet, though. Just wanted to get this up so others could use it. I have a very vague hypothesis that it will happen after 26 iterations, but this is completely unsupported.

EDIT: Thanks to @Ross Millikan in the comments, the answer is actually 1260 - the highest LCM of a set of numbers with a sum of 26. The reason this works is because there can be "loops" where A is substituted with B, B with C, and C with A. This loop has a size of 3. The loops in a substitution cipher can sum to 26, and the 1260 figure comes from loops of 4, 5, 7, and 9 and an extra letter that is substituted with itself. If this isn't legal, then the actual amount is something else - I'll find that eventually.

Comment: That would be the upper bound, right? (11*17*19*21*23*24*45*26, if anyone's interested)

Comment: @EngineerToast Yes - it can happen earlier, but it will always happen after that many iterations.

Comment: The maximum cycle length is the greatest number that is the LCM of a set of numbers summing to 26.  This is given in http://oeis.org/A000793 as $1260=4\cdot 9 \cdot 5\cdot 7$  If you break the permutation into cycles, the overall cycle length is the LCM of the lengths of the various cycles.

Comment: If you don't need an exact answer, then you could say that it will happen by the 26th iteration

Comment: @KSmarts No, because if A-->B, B-->C, and C-->A then it won't be the same after 26 iterations. The reason Ross Millikan's 1260 works is because the length of these "loops" must sum to 26.

Comment: So this was just a cryptogram? The Caesar thing was a red herring?

Comment: @xnor As far as I know, yes. I don't really see the point in the Caesar clue *or* the cryptogram itself.

Comment: What I meant was, it will happen at the 26th iteration or sooner. But, I didn't actually do the decoding, so the title had me thinking it was a Caesar cipher. Since it isn't, I think @RossMillikan has the correct least upper bound.

Comment: I have only shown that it happens by the $1260$th iteration.  If you have two loops of $13$ it will repeat every $13$ iterations and $13$ does not divide into $1260$.  Engineer Toast has the answer for the first iteration that is guaranteed to be the same as the original.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ahh, ok. Thanks for clearing that up.